# Not posting to database

Tags: c#, php

I'm pretty new with this Database / server stuff, so please bear with me. I'm having trouble figuring out why these variables aren't posting to my DB from Unity.

- My DB connection information is correct, as other posts are working.

here's my php:
- I've replaced the $_POST variables below with non-post variables and they work just fine! So I'm relatively happy with my php code.

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$DBusername = "id*****_zingzingzingbah";
$DBpassword = "*******";
$DBName = "id430563_fitness2017";


$firstname = $_POST["firstnamePOST"];   
$lastname = $_POST["lastnamePOST"]; 
$username = $_POST["usernamePOST"]; 
$email = $_POST["emailPOST"];           
$password = $_POST["passwordPOST"]; 

//$firstname = "aaaa";  
//$lastname =  "aaaa";  
//$username = "aaaa";   
//$email = "aaaa";          
//$password =  "aaaa";  

// Make Connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername,$DBusername, $DBpassword, $DBName);

// Check Connection
if (!$conn) {
    die ("Connection Failed. ". mysqli_connect_error());
} else { echo "Connection Success" ; // display some text or info on the screen }

$sql = "INSERT INTO user_info (firstname, lastname, username, email, password) VALUES('".$firstname."','".$lastname."','".$username."','".$email."','".$password."')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if(!$result) {      
    echo "there was an error creating user specific table"; 
} else {
    echo "Everything OK2";
}
```

?>

See Unity C# code below...
- I have two CreateUser functions below so that the void one, can be accessed  from Unity... I had trouble accessing IEnumerator functions otherwise.
- the code gets stuck after `insertUserInfo = new WWW (InsertUserInfoURL,form);`
- the yield return isn't returning.

```
    public void CreateUser(string inputFirstname, string inputLastname, string inputUsername,string inputEmail,string inputPassword ){
    StartCoroutine (CreateUser2 (inputFirstname,inputLastname,inputUsername,inputEmail,inputPassword));
}

private IEnumerator CreateUser2(string inputFirstname, string inputLastname, string inputUsername,string inputEmail,string inputPassword ){

    WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
    inputFirstname = "bbb";
    inputLastname = "bbb";
    inputUsername = "bbb";
    inputEmail = "bbb";
    inputPassword = "bbb";

    form.AddField ("firstnamePOST", inputFirstname);
    form.AddField ("lastnamePOST", inputLastname);
    form.AddField ("usernamePOST", inputUsername);
    form.AddField ("emailPOST", inputEmail);
    form.AddField ("passwordPOST", inputPassword);

    print("getting here ok");
    insertUserInfo = new WWW (InsertUserInfoURL,form);
    yield return insertUserInfo;
    print("why aren't you getting here");
```

- I'm sure the URL is correct (base on test without POST variables)
- I'm sure the DB info is correct (base on test without POST variables)
- I'm sure the SQL code is correct (base on test without POST variables)
- I'm definitely calling the CreateUser functions (both of them)
- would appreciate any tips on troubleshooting this stuff, because I feel like I'm fumbling in the dark

thanks guys!

Comment: Have you tried using a HTTP debugger such as Fiddler2?

Comment: *"I'm relatively happy with my php code"* - You won't be if you get hit with an sql injection; use a prepared statement. Not to mention using plain text passwords. You're not live or going live with this, are you?

Comment: Hash your users passwords.. Where does this fail? `POST` values don't make it to the PHP?

Comment: I've erased some comments; maybe you thought they were irrelevant; in any which case, you may have left the question (as I have now) or waiting for magic; well, I do perform a trick or two, just not in this case; good luck and do respond to comments; they help shed some light on all this.

Comment: @JohnSmith never used a HTTP debugger before, but will give it a go! thanks!

Comment: @Fred-ii- This is just personal use, not going live... I'm happy with the php code, with regards to it Posting to the DB properly - though obviously I've missed something somewhere

Comment: @chris85 Hey Chris, the yield return isn't returning.... or my code gets stuck there. The POST values definitely don't get to my online database (my non POST values do) I'm struggling to check wehther the values make it to my PHP because it's not returning! about to try this debugger tool

Comment: Check your error logs... or make line 2 `die(print_r($POST, 1));` then comment out the rest of the code. That should atleast tell you if the `POST` is sending. If so we can remove the C# code and tag. The less code to debug the easier.

Comment: @chris85 Thanks Chris. I did as you suggested, but my the result is not returning to the Unity console. It's still freezing at `insertUserInfo = new WWW (InsertUserInfoURL,form); yield return insertUserInfo;` and nothing is printed....

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Unity console` but if the `C#` is failing the PHP is unrelated. Make a form or CURL and send a request to the PHP page. If you get the response you can confirm the PHP is working and this is a sending issue from the C#.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I finally figured it out...

I was changing my scene in Unity before the WWW request had time to resolve..

probably down to horrible coding on my behalf!

thanks everyone for your comments